# Compile timeout on Overleaf even after commenting out chunks

Tags: compiling, overleaf, comments

When I added a lot.. way a lot of text and information at once on a .tex file in overleaf, I encounter a compile timeout message because the compiling seem to take forever (I have a basic account)

`Sorry, your compile took too long to run and timed out.`

I still get the above message. The compile still took forever after I just commented out the huge chunk of text and information from the .text file that I just added onto it.

Should not the compile take shorter/usual time after commenting out after encountering the error in the first place?

Comment: Overleaf-specific questions should be posted to the Overleaf Helpdesk. Overleaf's LaTeX support team is top notch.

Comment: you are very unlikely to time out on an error free document. If your document  is looping it will always timeout. Start by deleting all cached files (a button at the bottom of the view log page)